# The usage of "setting forth"

Tags: grammar

> Matters such as standards on setting forth the aforementioned plans and disposal guidelines shall be expressly established by the central government authorities of different industries.

Is the phrase "on setting forth" grammatically correct in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "setting forth" fits here in the sentence and is grammatically correct.

Comment: Thanks, but what about placing "on" in front of "setting forth"? Is it still correct?

Comment: @elee I don't see why it's wrong. You could use "of" instead of "on"

Comment: or '*for*' even